# Doesn't work onscroll javascript

Tags: javascript, events, onscroll

I want to do `console.log()`  when page scrolled to the last block `#scroll`, but it doesn`t working:

```
<div id="posts">my very own posts</div>
<div id="scroll" style="height:300px; width:100%" onscroll="onScroll()"></div>
  <script>
  function onScroll(){
    console.log('YES');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inside the `<div>`, so the content isn't scrolling.

The even listener always refers to the scrolling content of the object it is on.

Try putting it on the `<body>` tag.

```
<body onscroll="onScroll()">
  <p>lots of content. <p>lots of content. <p>lots of content
</body>
```

Or put stuff inside the `<div>` so it can scroll.

Comment: How can I do the same console.log('YES') when I scrolled to the end of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` needs to have `overflow: scroll;`, and have some content in there so it has its own scroll bar.

```
<div style="height:50px; width:100%; overflow: scroll;"  onscroll="onScroll()">
Blah
blah
<br>
some content
</div>
  <script>
  function onScroll(){
    console.log('YES');
  }
</script>
```